# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When I debug this code, I get this error on the "else" part of the if-statement. I am not very familiar with java script so any help would be great :)

```js
function doDDItemSelected() {
    var oSrc = event.srcElement
    var oCrit
    var oCritB
    var lstListItems
    var iCritPK = oSrc.getAttribute('CRIT_PK')
    oSrc.style.visibility = "hidden";
    oSrc.style.display = "none";

    if (oSrc.id.indexOf("lstCritB") != -1) {
        oCrit = $get('CritB' + iCritPK.toString());
        oCrit.value = oSrc.options[oSrc.selectedIndex].text;
    } else {
        oCrit = $get('Crit' + iCritPK.toString()); // error is in this line
        oCrit.value = oSrc.options[oSrc.selectedIndex].text;
        if (oCrit.onchange) {
            oCrit.onchange();
        }

        // Set the value of the end of range field if there is one
        try {
            oCritB = $get('CritB' + iCritPK.toString());
            if (oCritB.value == "") {
                if (oSrc.options[oSrc.selectedIndex].value != "(ALL)") {
                    oCritB.value = oSrc.options[oSrc.selectedIndex].text;
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I should add that this function is used in a selecting a drop down box in a web browser. The issue is that I cannot select items in the drop down box and have the selected item displayed in the same box. This code works in IE11 but not in Google Chrome.

Edit 2: Here is a screenshot of the debugger in google chrome
[image]

Comment: `iCritPK` is null.  Find out why using your debugger.

Comment: hi is this a Drag&Drop event

Comment: No this is selecting items from a drop down box. The issue is that they do not display into the box when selected. Works in Internet explorer but not google chrome.

Comment: hi see my answer   ,    its an event onchange="doDDItemSelected" right??

Answer (score 0):

Hi   try passing the event as a argument

`function doDDItemSelected(event) {`

Comment: so close! I am now able to click on the drop down list items but it still does not put the selected item into the drop down box.

Comment: pls can you attach a screen shot of the debugger and the page 

Comment: navigate to the Elements tab see  element dropdown  properties   like id,class,etc   whats the correct name  of the Attribute you trying to select  the NAME `CRIT_PK` is incorrect  also  you don't need  toString() delete it.

Answer (score -1):

its because that variable is the result of a call to the method `getAttribute` which, will return null if it is not set. `null` does not contain the method 'toString', so the error is correctly being raised.

Perhaps thinking of doing an `else if` case which checks that the value is explicitly not null.

```
... 
}
else if ( iCritPK !== null ) { 
...
```

Comment: The error is thrown because you cannot call a method on a null object, *not* because "null cannot be converted to a string"

Comment: fair... thats what I meant... I'll change the language for correctness. thanks

Comment: It's still wrong.  You cannot access a member of a null object.  Attempts to dereference a null object to access a member will result in this exception.

Comment: If you attempt to call a method that does not exist on an object that does exist, you will get a different error.  `var x = {};  x.foo()` will throw a `TypeError: x.foo is not a function`.  Contrast this to `var y = null; y.foo()`.  In the question, the error is not thrown because the object does not contain the method; it's thrown because there is no object.